# Asynchronous callback is running in which thread when I use SmartThreadPool?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, threadpool

First I append a task to SmartThreadPool (http://smartthreadpool.codeplex.com/)

```
SmartThreadPool _threadPool = new SmartThreadPool()
_threadPool.QueueWorkItem(Process, state);
```

And in the *Process* method.

```
private static void Process(object state)
{
    // ...
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
    request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(OnResponse), request);
    return;
}
```

**Question:** *OnResponse* is running in which thread? how can I make the callback also run in the SmartThreadPool?

```
static void OnResponse(IAsyncResult ar)
{

}
```

Comment: It will be running in `ThreadPool` Thread. you can verify using `Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread` property. Why do you want to invoke it in SmartThreadPool Thread?

Comment: is it possible to replace the default ThreadPool?

Comment: AFAIK the answer is no, why do you want to do so? what are you trying to achieve?